# what is Vmlinuz file on live ubuntu?

Tags: boot, directory

I use **Ubuntu 14.04** live on flash. In my computer directory there is a file name **vmlinuz**

What is this file? I did not have that on my 12.04 on hard derive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Vmlinuz file** is the name of Linux kernel executable , by other word its a compressed Linux kernel and it is bootable .

**Vmlinuz** is located in `/boot` directory , it may be the **actual** kernel executable or a **link** to the real one , you can use ls -l /boot to know if its a link or not .

The life map of this file it gets uncompressed, loaded into memory, and executed at boot , then you see your operating system .

By the way its also included in all Ubuntu release , its a basic part of operating system   .